# WPF infragistics XamComboEditor shows string.Length in display for bound list of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

XamComboEditor itemssource is set to List, it is not displaying the actual string instead it is showing its length. How do i make it to show the actual string from the list.

```
<Infragistics:XamComboEditor x:Name="cboSearchMemberMultiSelect" CheckBoxVisibility="Visible"  Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="2" Width="150" Visibility="Collapsed" AllowMultipleSelection="True" SelectionChanged="cboSearchMemberMultiSelect_SelectionChanged"  />
```

In XAml.cs

```
 private List<string> StudentTypeItems()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Student");
        list.Add("Ambassador");
        list.Add("Crew");
        return list;
    }
```

cboSearchMemberMultiSelect.ItemsSource=StudentTypeItems();

It is the problem in only displaying the values. but otherwise if i debug i can see the items as usual. it is very strange.

Comment: Could you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

What i thought about this behaviour is. The WPF binding system will bind only with properties insteed of classes and the list of string is basically a List of String Class which means the items binding coud be done with the properties of the String class. and the String class is having only Length Property. thats why its binding with length property by default.

if you create new class. say employee and add a name property. now create a list of employees and then  the child element of listbox can ge biding with name property of the Employee class.

hopefully this solves you problem.

Comment: No, its not possible, You can check with normal combobox , it will not have any issue.problem is with Infragistics combobox control not with WPF.

Comment: XamComboEditor does not support binding to simple type such as strings, ints etc. The best thing to do if you encounter this or any other issue is to wrap the string in a custom object and set the display member path to point to the string prop that contains the string that should be displayed.